# Do we have the support in iOS latest version for OMA DM?

Tags: ios

I am interested to write an application for OMA DM ( Device Management ) for iPod Touch.Do we have the support in iOS latest version for OMA DM?, so that i can use them.

Please refer any document link if any.

Regards
Bhaskar

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do with OMA DM support with Iphone or any other OS. OMA DM is generally used to push service specific parameters to handsets or firmwares. I don't think iOS exposes any OMA DM interface at all to any of its devices.

Comment: guarav, the whole microsoft management platform is built on oma-dm. [Link](http://openmobilealliance.org/windows-intune/).